# Does HTTPS Effect HTML Pages?

Tags: html, https, cpanel

So i have a HTML file in my cPanel File Manager and i want to edit it.
Here's an example

My HTML Line

```
<a class="/">My Home</a>
```

My HTML Line (Edited)

```
<a class="/">Home</a>
```

I want to see the preview,so i type in my website url on my browser. The HTML was edited successfully in HTTP.

But when i go to HTTPS,it doesn't change at all. It's still says "My Home". Does HTTPS effect this kind of stuff? Need Help Please :)

Thank You

Comment: Reload the page with `Ctrl` + `F5` to clear the cache.

Comment: Or `Shift` + `F5` On chrome

Answer (score -1):

You might have another www-root for https than for http...

Comment: You might want to have a look on this thread: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/https-as-separate-folder-can-i-set-this.102745/

Comment: Cpanel not use www-root for https.

Comment: Oh yea,so turns out not using www actually does the trick. Thanks :)